# Automate the conversion of “inorder/infix” expressions to the corresponding “PostOrder” and “PreOrder” expressions using “Expression Trees

Tags: c, tree, stack, binary-tree

Please I am really struggling with an assignment of trees and stacks in C. I could really need some help. To summarize the assignment we are asked to change an equation or expression from inOrder to PostOrder and PreOrder expressions using Expression Trees. It also stated that once built,we have to traverse the expression tree in one of the three traversals we LNR, LRN, NLR. Finally for the implementation the professor asked us to do it using stacks in building the expression trees

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] of your own attempt and [edit] your question to show it together with a description of the problems you have with it.

Comment: I down voted your "what supposed to be a question". You are just telling what professor asked, but not what your problem is. Read the help pages and try again.

Answer (score 0):

When you visit a tree recursively, you have control over when you process the current node in relation to when you process its children.

Consider the difference between the following three visitors for a binary tree:

```
void visit1(Node *node) {
   if (!node)
      return;

   do_something(node);
   visit1(node->left);
   visit1(node->right);
}

void visit2(Node *node) {
   if (!node)
      return;

   visit2(node->left);
   do_something(node);
   visit2(node->right);
}

void visit3(Node *node) {
   if (!node)
      return;

   visit3(node->left);
   visit3(node->right);
   do_something(node);
}
```

Don't see it? Consider a tree representing `(1-2)+(3-4)`.

```
            op:+
       ____/   \____
      /             \
    op:-            op:-
   /   \           /   \
num:1  num:2    num:3  num:4
```

For each of the three visitors, what's the order of the calls to `do_something` for the tree?